# Java file writing glitches

Tags: java, json

I have been working on a Java application for a few months now and I have just recently experienced an odd bug.

User data is currently saved to a bunch of nested HashMaps and after it is saved then another thread comes in, reads the hash maps, converts it to son, and writes it to a file. My class that I use to write the join to the file uses Google Gson and the format of this son is predefined. The class just iterates through the HashMaps and takes the values and fills it into the json.

```
public static void writeFile(String fileLocation) {
    workingFile = fileLocation;
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    JsonWriter writer;
    try {
        File file = new File(fileLocation);
        writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));

        String[] days = { "saturday", "sunday" };
        String[] times = { "am", "pm" };

        writer.beginObject();
        for (String day : days) {
            writer.name(day);
            writer.beginObject();
            writer.name("date").value(data.get(day).getDate());
            writer.name("races");
            writer.beginObject();
            for (String time : times) {
                writer.name(time);
                writer.beginObject();
                for (Division division : Division.values()) {
                    writer.name(division.getName());
                    writer.beginObject();
                    if (time.equals("am")) {
                        writer.name("elimination").value("double");
                    } else if (time.equals("pm")) {
                        writer.name("elimination").value("single");
                    }
                    writer.name("defined").value(data.get(day).getTime(time).getRace(division).getDefined());
                    writer.name("racers").value(data.get(day).getTime(time).getRace(division).getRacers());
                    writer.name("heats");
                    writer.beginArray();
                    if (data.get(day).getTime(time).getRace(division).getDefined()) {
                        for (Entry<Integer, Heat> heat : data.get(day).getTime(time).getRace(division)
                                .getSheet().heats.entrySet()) {

                            String driver_1 = heat.getValue().getDriver1();
                            String time_1a = heat.getValue().getDriver1PhaseAString();
                            String time_1b = heat.getValue().getDriver1PhaseBString();
                            String driver_2 = heat.getValue().getDriver2();
                            String time_2a = heat.getValue().getDriver2PhaseAString();
                            String time_2b = heat.getValue().getDriver2PhaseBString();
                            String differential = heat.getValue().getDifferentialString();
                            String winner = heat.getValue().getWinner();
                            String loser = heat.getValue().getLoser();

                            writer.beginObject();
                            writer.name("heat").value(heat.getValue().getHeatNumber());
                            writer.name("driver_1").value(driver_1);
                            writer.name("time_1a").value(time_1a);
                            writer.name("time_1b").value(time_1b);
                            writer.name("driver_2").value(driver_2);
                            writer.name("time_2a").value(time_2a);
                            writer.name("time_2b").value(time_2b);
                            writer.name("differential").value(differential);
                            writer.name("winner").value(winner);
                            writer.name("loser").value(loser);
                            writer.name("progress").value(heat.getValue().getProgress());
                            writer.name("force_completed").value(heat.getValue().getForceCompleted());
                            writer.name("drivers_paired").value(heat.getValue().driversPaired());
                            writer.endObject();

                        }
                    }
                    writer.endArray();
                    writer.name("results");
                    writer.beginObject();
                    if (data.get(day).getTime(time).getRace(division).getDefined()) {
                        for (Entry<Integer, ResultField> resultField : data.get(day).getTime(time).getRace(division)
                                .getSheet().resultFields.entrySet()) {
                            writer.name(resultField.getKey().toString()).value(resultField.getValue().getText());
                        }
                    }
                    writer.endObject();
                    writer.name("failed uploads");
                    writer.beginArray();
                    if (data.get(day).getTime(time).getRace(division).getDefined()) {
                        for (int heat : data.get(day).getTime(time).getRace(division).getSheet().failed_uploads) {
                            writer.value(heat);
                        }
                    }
                    writer.endArray();
                    writer.endObject();
                }
                writer.endObject();
            }
            writer.endObject();
            writer.endObject();
        }
        writer.endObject();

        writer.close();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Done! File written in " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000000 + " ms.");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

An odd thing happened today, which of course happened while I was giving a demo. I made a change through the user interface of my program, and it had looked like the data was saved. When I quit the application completely there was no data to be read in that file. Yes I checked that I had saved it to the right file. The actual json formatting was there, except where my values should have been there was nothing.

It is as if the file was writing, it tried to read for my variables, but they were erased. Could I have quit the application while the file was being written, and the variable it needed were no longer there?

The question: Am I handling saving data correctly? I am unable to reproduce this bug, which worries me because I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Closing resource should be ensured, so `writer.close();` shouldn't be part of `try` (nor `catch`) section, but `finally`. Or even better use try-with-resources which will generate finally section witch closing resources for you automatically.

Comment: Did you flush your output stream before exiting your program? (Closing most steam implementations will cause the stream to be flushed, but you need to consult with the exact implementations you're using to validate that.)

Comment: Independent of having a bug in there: read about the **Single layer of abstraction** principle. Your code benefit from that. Very much it could. You see, one problem with your code (that makes it also **hard** for strangers to figure what is going on!) is that you are doing **way too many** things within that single poor method. Prefer to write many many small (3, 5 lines max) instead.